Can't run app on Android Studio Koala (2024.1.1 Patch 1) - keyboard obstructs text box
Problem
Upon running the emulator for a simple app with a text box, the keyboard obstructs the view of some of the text and so you can't see the bottom of the textbox . Packages used are outlined below. Used the empty views activity template and added a a line “setContentView(R.layout.note_layout);” which contains some text boxes and buttons.
Image of issue here: https://i.sstatic.net/26grYGQM.png
Desired Output
Keyboard does not obstruct text, and textbox adjusts so user can scroll to bottom of text box and observe contents.
Packages Used

Android studio version: Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1

Template: empty views activity (MainActivity.java below) - Emulator phone version:  Pixel 6a API 35


Attempts to solve the problem:

In attribute panel, selected “vertical” in scrollbar menu

Inserted “android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize” under application section in androidManifeest.xml


Relevant Code/Files
- MainActivity.java
package learnprogramming.academy;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge; import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; import androidx.core.graphics.Insets; import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat; import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.note_layout);
    
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
    }

- note_layout.xml 

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/main" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextMultiLine2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="The OK button is now constrained vertically, to remain lined up with the baseline of the Cancel button. A baseline constraint like this is different to constraining the top or bottom of the button. In this case, it's the text that lines up - so if the buttons are different heights, the layout looks better, because the text is aligned.  When it was constrained to the bottom edge of the layout, that allowed me to drag it up and down the screen - the only thing that changed was the distance from the bottom of the layout. Now, though, it's constrained to the Cancel button. If I try to drag it up or down, nothing happens.  I can still drag it left or right, which just changes its margin from the Cancel button, but it can no longer be moved up or down.  Even cooler, watch what happens when I drag the Cancel button up or down! When the Cancel button moves up or down, the OK button follows it, because of the vertical constraint.  Whether I'd constrained the top, bottom or baseline, that would still be the case, the OK button can't be moved vertically because it's constrained to the Cancel button, and when the Cancel button moves vertically the OK button follows.  Notice that when the OK button's selected, the Inspector shows a downwards arrow to indicate that there is a constraint, but you can't change the margin value like you can with the constraint to the right. Baseline constraints don't have margins."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="OK"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        tools:text="OK" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

